# How to sort search results by relevance in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting, search

I'm building a custom search, as of now if I enter "The R" I get the result list with The Fellow ship of the Ring first, because the phrase "the ring" it's in its .text. I want The Return of the King to be first. Is there a way I can give more relevance to the .name field or sort the match array based on the name .field and the input text?

HTML

```
<section class="container-fluid px-0 justify-content-center">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center search">
      <form class="form-inline position-relative">
        <input id="search" class="form-control form-control-search" type="text" placeholder="Search..." aria-label="Search">
      </form>
      <div id="match-list" class="d-none"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
const searchIndex = async searchText => {
 const res = await fetch('/data/index.json');
 const index = await res.json();

  matchList.classList.remove("d-none");
 // Get matches to current text input
 let matches = index.filter(index => {
  const regex = new RegExp(`${searchText}`, 'gi');
  return index.name.match(regex) || index.text.match(regex);
 });

 // Clear when input or matches are empty
 if (searchText.length === 0) {
   clearSearch();
 }

 outputHtml(matches);
};

function clearSearch(){
  matches = [];
  matchList.classList.add("d-none");
}

// Show results in HTML
const outputHtml = matches => {
 if (matches.length > 0) {
  const html = matches.map(function(match){
      return `<a href="${match.url}">
      <div class="media mb-2">
        <div class="component-icon-slot my-auto" style="background-image: url('/img/${match.url}/icon.png"></div>
          <div class="media-body pl-2">
            <h3 class="mt-0 mb-0">${match.name}</h3>
            <b>${match.type}</b><br/>
            <i>Found in <b>${match.product}</b></i><br/>
            ${match.text}
          </div>
        </div></a>`
    }
}).join('');
  matchList.innerHTML = html;
 }
};
```

index.JSON

```
 [
  {
    "name": "The Fellowship of the Rings",
    "type": "book",
    "text": "Bilbo reveals that he intends to leave the Shire for one last adventure, and he leaves his inheritance, including the Ring, to his nephew Frodo. Gandalf investigates...",
    "url": "books/the-fellowship-of-the-rings",
    "product": "Books"
  },
  {
    "name": "The Two Towers",
    "type": "book",
    "text": "Awakening from a dream of Gandalf fighting the Balrog in Moria, Frodo Baggins and Samwise Gamgee find themselves lost in the Emyn Muil near Mordor and discover they are being tracked by Gollum, a former bearer of the One Ring.",
    "url": "books/the-two-towers",
    "product": "Books"
  },
  {
    "name": "The Return of the King",
    "type": "book",
    "text": "Gandalf flies in with eagles to rescue the Hobbits, who awaken in Minas Tirith and are reunited with the surviving Fellowship.",
    "url": "books/the-return-of-the-king",
    "product": "Books"
  }
]
```

Comment: This question doesn't have a clear answer. You can have different strategies to rate relevance.

Comment: I'd be fine with wathever solution that prioritize name and then text.

Comment: Is it enough for you to have it ranked by match/no match or you need something more fancy?

Comment: I'm trying to sort them by relevance, so, the name first, then the text. Optionally I'd try to search also from the start of the string, I've used RegExp(`^${searchText}`, 'gi'); but if I write just "king" I would get no results.

Comment: You shouldn't just use regular expression like that, because regular expressions use special characters. Instead, compare if `string.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())`.

Comment: I've changed     let matches = index.filter(index => {
      return index.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()) || index.text.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
    });

Comment: You're on a good track. You can keep `searchText.toLowerCase()` stored outside the loop to prevent lowercasing on each iteration. Also, consider mapping your array to add the score. You can add 1 to the score if text contains it and add 2 if the name contains it, for example. So that would make it maximum of 3 points, name being the stronger value. Just throwing ideas. Once you have the score in the mapped result, it's easy to sort by that value.

Comment: I like the points ideas, I've thought about that too but I'm not so skilled, also I don't know what you mean with toLowerCase() out of the loop. Could you add an answer with an example of the point system? So i can select the preferred answer and make some try.

Comment: I just did. Please have a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could map your data to include relevance points:

```js
const index = await res.json();
const searchTextLowercased = searchText.toLowerCase();

const rankedIndex = index.map(entry => {
    let points = 0;

    if (entry.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTextLowercased)) {
        points += 2;
    }

    if (entry.text.toLowerCase().includes(searchTextLowercased)) {
        points += 1;
    }

    return {...entry, points};
}).sort((a, b) => b.points - a.points);
```

This way, you have ranked results in `rankedIndex` const.

Keep in mind that your code probably needs some refactoring, because you're fetching data on each search. I'm assuming your `searchIndex()` is called with every key press or something like that.

Comment: It works but it has an issue, for some reason it appen that some result have 4 points. So if I write the letter "a" but some result has more matches in the text, it will be above even if it's name starts with the letter "c".

Comment: It's not possible if you used my code as I posted it.

Comment: I just renamed rankedIndex in matches becasue the script use that. I haven't done any other modification.